# Rescaling logistic regression coefficients such that variance remains constant

Tags: regression, logistic, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, estimators

I'm reading "[A Modern Maximum-Likelihood Theory for High-dimensional Logistic Regression](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.06964.pdf)" by Pragya Sur, and trying to recreate Figure 2, for my own edification. The covariates, $X$, are i.i.d. $N(0,1/n)$, where $n=4000$ and there are $p=800$ predictors. I put together a python simulation to sample from that distribution, assign the true $\beta$'s as indicated in the paper (the first $100$ $\beta$'s are equal to $10$, the next $100$ are equal to $-10$, and the remaining 600 are equal to $0$. I then get the responses according to a logistic model and do a logistic regression to compare the estimated coefficients to the true coefficients.

My results are off by a bit and I think it's because in the paper they say to scale the coefficients in such a way that $$Var(\textbf{X}_{i}'\boldsymbol{\beta})=5.$$ And I'm able to find that $$Var(\textbf{X}_{i}'\boldsymbol{\beta})=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^p {\beta}_{j}^2$$. So, in order for that expression to equal $5$, I should replace $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ with $$\boldsymbol{\beta}^*=\boldsymbol{\beta}\sqrt{5n/(\sum_{j=1}^p {\beta}_{j}^2)}.$$ So then $Var(\textbf{X}_{i}'\boldsymbol{\beta}^*)=5$. If this is not correct, how exactly do I rescale the coefficients and how should I implement it? I am currently replacing $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ with $\boldsymbol{\beta}^*$ when computing the true response values. I'm also not sure if I need to scale the estimates $\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}$ computed by the logistic regression.